# Post-apocalyptic movie about a soldier fighting a war against robots who thinks he's the last human on Earth until he meets a girl

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, post-apocalyptic

A long time ago I watched a movie where a soldier was fighting a war against robots I think, and he was the only one left of his platoon and he thinks the only human left on Earth.

He meets a girl who's running from the robots and she convinces him to let her stay with him and his dog. He goes on a scouting mission and while she's taking a bath, some drones come in and she and the dog hide underwater and the drones explode somehow? He thinks she's dead and goes to get revenge and then she comes back and he finds out she's alive.

It's been a long time since I watched this but it's killing me to know what the name of it was. If anyone could help that would be amazing!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket. - Neither of those films are really post-apocalyptic. Also, neither of the protagonists in those films believed they were the last man on Earth.

Comment: Quite right, I meant Minority Report and I Am Legend. @LogicDictates

Comment: *Screamers* has a man thinking he's the last person alive (from his platoon) and meeting a woman, but no bathtub scene. As noted, *Minority Report* does have a scene where Tom Cruise's character hides from a drone by submersing in water.

Answer (score 4):

### [The Last Sentinel](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheLastSentinel)?

> Humans lost a war against the drone police, created to serve humanity in the first place. When Tallis, a grizzled ex-soldier and survivor rescues an amnesiac young woman and takes her in as his partner, they will have to fight their way out against a seemingly endless horde of mechanical enemies.

It has everything: Drones, a woman. Everything.

[image]

Comment: Including Don "The Dragon" Wilson of *Bloodsport* fame!

Comment: {raised eyebrow} And Keith David voices... a gatling gun?